# Populating a drop down list based on the option selected in other drop down box

Tags: html, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, odata

I have an `HTML` page in an `Asp.Net MVC 4` application in which I have several `dropdown` lists to deal with. In one case I am trying to populate a `dropdown` list with results based on the value selected in the first `dropdown` box.

For Example, I have an SQL table with following structure

```
Id    ProductName   GradeName
1       Petroleum      A
2       Petroleum      B
3       Petroleum      C
4       Grains         1
5       Grains         2
6       Grains         3
```

So, when I select `Petroleum` in `Product` List then my `Grade` list should be populated with `A,B,C`

**Knockout Js and Odata**

```
var GradeViewModel = function () {

     $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: '/odata/Grades',
            data: ko.toJSON(self.grades),
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                self.gradeNames((ko.utils.arrayMap(data.value, function (grade) {
                    var obsGrade = {
                        Id: grade.Id,
                        ProductName: ko.observable(grade.ProductName),
                        GradeName: ko.observable(grade.GradeName),
                        Edit: ko.observable(false),

                        Locked: ko.observable(grade.Locked)
                    }
                    self.watchModel(obsGrade, self.modelChanged);
                    return obsGrade;
                })));
            }
        });



}

 GradeViewModel.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
            var filter = GradeViewModel.selectedChoice();

            if (!filter) {
                return GradeViewModel.gradeNames();
            } else {

                var filtered = ko.utils.arrayFilter(GradeViewModel.gradeNames(), function (item) {
                    return (item.ProductName() === filter);
                });

                return filtered
            }
        })

      var viewModel = new GradeViewModel();
     ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**HTML**

```
<td>

 <select data-bind="options: $root.gradeNames, optionsText: 'ProductName', optionsValue: 'ProductName', value: selectedChoice, optionsCaption: 'Product'">
  </select>
 </td>

 <td>   
 <select data-bind="options: $root.gradeNames, optionsText: 'GradeName', optionsValue: 'GradeName', enable:selectedChoice, value: selectedGrade, optionsCaption: 'Grade'">
 </select>
 </td>
```

May I know a good way to do it.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you don't need to (and shouldn't) include words from tags in your title... check out the FAQ for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you already have the relevant data, no need in querying via a `subscription`. So for this particular case, I would use one of the available [utility methods](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html).

- **ko.utils.arrayFilter**

  ```
  viewModel.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
    var filter = viewModel.selectedChoice();

    if (!filter) { 
     return viewModel.gradeNames();
    } else {

      var filtered = ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.gradeNames(), function (item) {
        return (item.ProductName() === filter);
      });

      return filtered;
    } 
  })
  ```

The html for the `GradeName` select would then become

```
 <select data-bind="options: $root.filteredItems, optionsText: 'GradeName', optionsValue: 'GradeName', enable:selectedChoice, value: selectedGrade, optionsCaption: 'Grade'">
```

Reference this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/EwLLL/).

Comment: I tried it but it threw me a type error saying GradeviewModel.selectedChoice() is not function. I have edited the question with your answer. Please check

Comment: For future reference if you are making code changes to a post, append them at the end as some historical reference information is lost/replaced by the modifications.

Comment: Sure, Thanks were you able to see the changes for now

Comment: Inside of your ajax you use `self.gradeNames`, the filtering computed would need to be added to `self` instead of `GradeViewModel` and the references within it would need to be replaced by `self`. Whatever object is defined as `$root` is the object that needs to contain the computed. So the problem you now face is `GradeViewModel.selectedChoice()` doesn't exist since `selectedChoice` is defined in $root/self. At least that is the way it reads from what is available, contextually to me, through the code provided.